# Use register for .NET sosex extension

Tags: windbg, sosex

Is there any way to display the object contents using `!mdt` (SOSEX extension) but using a register?

I am aware if you do `!mdt 299281` (display the object in that address if any) but what about if I want to do `!mdt edx` (register instead of hex number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use `@edx`. Here's an example with `eax`:

```
0:004> r
eax=023c3e64 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=773af1da esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=7732000c esp=04acfe88 ebp=04acfeb4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7732000c cc              int     3

0:004> !mdt @eax
023c3e64 (System.Globalization.CultureData)
    sRealName:023c1228 (System.String) 
    sWindowsName:023c1228 (System.String) 
    sName:023c1228 (System.String) 
    sParent:023c1228 (System.String) 
[...]
```